# How to add dropout layer in the TensorFlow?? And How to augment Numpy array in python 3.x?

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning

First of all, I am new to this field and I am trying to add the dropout layer to see the change in performance in my model. I am unable to figure out where and how should I add a dropout layer in the following code.
Moreover, I want to do data augmentation (shifting) to the numpy array of size 39*200 such a way that the first column shifts to second, second shifts to third and so on. And the last one shifts the first one. It's like cutting the last portion of the image and pasting it to the first.

```
def conv2d(x, W, b, strides=1):
x = tf.nn.conv2d(x, W, strides=[1, strides, strides, 1], padding='SAME')
x = tf.nn.bias_add(x, b)
return tf.nn.relu(x) 

def maxpool2d(x, k=2):
return tf.nn.max_pool(x, ksize=[1, k, k, 1], strides=[1, k, k, 1],padding='SAME')

weights = {
'wc1': tf.get_variable('W0', shape=(3,3,1,32), initializer=tf.contrib.layers.xavier_initializer()), 
'wc2': tf.get_variable('W1', shape=(3,3,32,64), initializer=tf.contrib.layers.xavier_initializer()), 
'wc3': tf.get_variable('W2', shape=(3,3,64,32), initializer=tf.contrib.layers.xavier_initializer()), 
'wc4': tf.get_variable('W3', shape=(3,3,32,128), initializer=tf.contrib.layers.xavier_initializer()),
'wc5': tf.get_variable('W4', shape=(3,3,128,64), initializer=tf.contrib.layers.xavier_initializer()),
'wd1': tf.get_variable('W7', shape=(4*4*56,64), initializer=tf.contrib.layers.xavier_initializer()), 
'out': tf.get_variable('W8', shape=(64,n_classes), initializer=tf.contrib.layers.xavier_initializer()),
```

}

```
biases = {
'bc1': tf.get_variable('B0', shape=(32), initializer=tf.contrib.layers.xavier_initializer()),
'bc2': tf.get_variable('B1', shape=(64), initializer=tf.contrib.layers.xavier_initializer()),
'bc3': tf.get_variable('B2', shape=(32), initializer=tf.contrib.layers.xavier_initializer()),
'bc4': tf.get_variable('B3', shape=(128), initializer=tf.contrib.layers.xavier_initializer()),
'bc5': tf.get_variable('B4', shape=(64), initializer=tf.contrib.layers.xavier_initializer()),
'bd1': tf.get_variable('B7', shape=(64), initializer=tf.contrib.layers.xavier_initializer()),
'out': tf.get_variable('B8', shape=(2), initializer=tf.contrib.layers.xavier_initializer()),
```

}

```
def conv_net(x, weights, biases):  
conv1 = conv2d(x, weights['wc1'], biases['bc1'])
conv1 = maxpool2d(conv1, k=2)

conv2 = conv2d(conv1, weights['wc2'], biases['bc2'])
conv2 = maxpool2d(conv2, k=2)

conv3 = conv2d(conv2, weights['wc3'], biases['bc3'])
conv3 = maxpool2d(conv3, k=2)

conv4 = conv2d(conv3, weights['wc4'], biases['bc4'])
conv4 = maxpool2d(conv4, k=2)

conv5 = conv2d(conv4, weights['wc5'], biases['bc5'])
conv5 = maxpool2d(conv5, k=2)

fc1 = tf.reshape(conv5, [-1, weights['wd1'].get_shape().as_list()[0]])
fc1 = tf.add(tf.matmul(fc1, weights['wd1']), biases['bd1'])
fc1 = tf.nn.relu(fc1) 
out = tf.add(tf.matmul(fc1, weights['out']), biases['out'])
return out

pred = conv_net(x, weights, biases)

cost =tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits=pred, 
labels=y), name='Cost')



optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=learning_rate).minimize(cost)


correct_prediction = tf.equal(tf.argmax(pred, 1), tf.argmax(y, 1))
accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_prediction, tf.float32))

init = tf.global_variables_initializer(),


with tf.Session() as sess:
sess.run(init)
train_loss = []
test_loss = []
train_accuracy = []
test_accuracy = []

if not os.path.exists('summaries'):
    os.mkdir('summaries')
if not os.path.exists(os.path.join('summaries','first')):
    os.mkdir(os.path.join('summaries','first'))

summary_writer = tf.summary.FileWriter(os.path.join('summaries','first'), sess.graph)  

for i in range(training_iters):
    for batch in range(len(X_train)//batch_size):
        batch_x = X_train[batch*batch_size:min((batch+1)*batch_size,len(X_train))]
        batch_y = Y_train[batch*batch_size:min((batch+1)*batch_size,len(Y_train))]    
        opt = sess.run(optimizer, feed_dict={x: batch_x,
                                                          y: batch_y})
        loss, acc = sess.run([cost, accuracy], feed_dict={x: batch_x,
                                                          y: batch_y})
    print("Iter " + str(i) + ", Loss= " + \
                  "{:.6f}".format(loss) + ", Training Accuracy= " + \
                  "{:.5f}".format(acc))
    print("Optimization Finished!")

    test_acc,valid_loss = sess.run([accuracy,cost], feed_dict={x: X_test,y : Y_test})
    train_loss.append(loss)
    test_loss.append(valid_loss)
    train_accuracy.append(acc)
    test_accuracy.append(test_acc)

    print("Testing Accuracy:","{:.5f}".format(test_acc))
    print("Accuracy:", accuracy.eval({x: X_test, y: Y_test}))
```

code Link: [1]: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1BcbLAlVG0QR8QKToyij9gniQ7E9gvaCc/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Dropout

You can put the dropout layer after the max-pooling in a similar way to this:

```
# _____________ FIRST MAX POOLING LAYER _____________________
A_pool1 = tf.nn.max_pool(A_conv1)

# _____________ FIRST DROPOUT LAYER _____________________
A_out1 = tf.nn.dropout(x=A_pool1, rate=dropout_prob)

# _____________ SECOND CONVOLUTIONAL LAYER _____________________
A_conv2 = tf.nn.relu(tf.nn.conv2d(A_out1, W_conv2))
```

where the dropout_prob is the probability that each element of x is discarded.

Another example is available [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/estimators/cnn) where they put the dropout layer after the dense layer (at the end).

In your specific case, you can do this:

```
conv2 = maxpool2d(conv2, k=2)
A_out1 = tf.nn.dropout(x=conv2, rate=0.5)
conv3 = conv2d(A_out1, weights['wc3'], biases['bc3'])
```

## Data augmentation

To do this you can use the Numpy function roll as explained here [Numpy roll](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.roll.html)

```
array([8, 9, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7])
x2 = np.reshape(x, (2,5))

>>> x2
array([[0, 1, 2, 3, 4],
   [5, 6, 7, 8, 9]])

np.roll(x2, 1, axis=1)
array([[4, 0, 1, 2, 3],
       [9, 5, 6, 7, 8]])
```

Comment: Its not working. should not I define the dropout layer in the beginning?? since I am a beginner, Please be more specific.
Please add the lines in my code. Thank You :)

Comment: @Virtuall.Kingg can I have the code e.g. shared Colab notebook or a .py file because copying it from the pdf is not the best solution.

Comment: PFA
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1BcbLAlVG0QR8QKToyij9gniQ7E9gvaCc/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Thanks, @Virtuall.Kingg can you also attach a part of your data files? otherwise, I cannot test if it is working correctly or not.

Comment: My data is so large. I am having trouble uploading it. Please add the dropout layer in the code. Thank You :)

Comment: @Virtuall.Kingg I edited my answer and I added what I would do in your case. Hope it will help.

Comment: I will try that..Thank You very much :)

Comment: I am classifying two data and for that I used CNN. Now I am having some difficulty in visualizing histogram, learning rate or error graphs, scalars in tensorboard. Also, I want to add sensitivity and specificity in my code. How to get TP, TN, FP, FN from my model?? What changes should I make in my code?